# Entity framework model first foregin key column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-key-relationship

I have 3 entity (`Projects` / `Products` / `Negotiations`).

 Negotiations entity have a column named `ReferencedId` and `TypeId` which `ReferencedId` is foreign key for both Projects and Products table. 
`TypeId` has define `ReferencedId` is belong to which entity.
But when I call `context.SaveChanges();` to insert new message in `Negotiation` entity, this error has been thrown:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProjectNegotiation". The conflict occurred in database "MyMVCApp", table "dbo.Projects", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**EDIT :**
This is my model:

[image: My Model]

What can I do to use 1 column as foreign key for Negotiations entity and avoid of use 2 column for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the code which is responsible for this exception? And perhaps the few operations you're doing before.

Comment: It's conceptual problem and I don't have any code for this. Just I define new class and save it using entity framework and this error occured.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, well then show us the entities please.

Comment: Can you explain DB structure on which belongs your entities?

Comment: god. ur english. better post your entities structure.

Comment: Sorry for my english :"> I have edit my question and add model picture to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say - this is a conceptual problem.. you are misusing a Foreing Key. Don't do this!

Make Negotiations abstract, create ProductNegotiations and ProjectNegotiations as subclasses of Negotiations and define your navigation propterties there

Comment: So I can't do this? It's beter for me to define one column for my entity and set their relations.

Comment: You can't do this with a foreign key - a foreign key has a well defined target. And no it's not better - it's baaaaad database design.

Comment: Ok. In my database what I should do for Negotiation table? define 2 column as foreign key ?

Comment: Foreign keys also may not be null (you might remove the referential integrity to allow this). I'd recommend (since you use model first) making Negotiations abstract, create ProductNegotiations and ProjectNegotiations as subclasses of Negotiations and define your navigation propterties there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a single column as a (formal) foreign key constraint pointing to two tables.

You could do this using some variant of Table-per-type or table-per-hierarchy mapping ([here is an introductory article](http://lwang00.wordpress.com/2007/11/04/entity-mapping-table-per-type-and-table-per-hierarchy/))